# Ansible: run different plays on the same host as different users

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to manage two user accounts, which happen to be on the same host (`mylaptop`).  I have a separate play for each of them.  However, Ansible keeps executing both plays as the same user, despite what I wrote in my `inventory`:

```
[personal_computers]
mylaptop ansible_ssh_user=personal-user

[work_computers]
mylaptop ansible_ssh_user=work-user
```

This is the playbook (`test.yml`) I'm using for testing:

```
- hosts: personal_computers
  tasks:
    - debug: var={{ ansible_env.HOME }}

- hosts: work_computers
  tasks:
    - debug: var={{ ansible_env.HOME }}
```

When I run it with `ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml -vvvv`, I can see that all connections are made with user `work-user`, and both debug tasks return `/home/work-user`.  Is this a bug in ansible?  How can I accomplish what I need, i.e. running two plays as two different users?

I'm using ansible 1.9.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might as well use 2 distinct inventory hostnames and specify `ansible_ssh_host` host variable:

```
[personal_computers]
personal-laptop ansible_ssh_host=mylaptop ansible_ssh_user=personal-user

[work_computers]
work-laptop ansible_ssh_host=mylaptop ansible_ssh_user=work-user
```